# HTML join input textfied value to href when link is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've an input text field and a link, when pressing the link i want to get a url containing value of the input field like this:

if i write `roma` on the text field i want to go to the page `treatment/exportPDF/roma`.

What i tried:

```
<script>
    function getUsername(){
        return $(".username").Text();
    }
</script>
<div  class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="Paragraph">Select a username</label>
            <p>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input name="username" type="text" class="longInput1"/>
                <span class="errorMessage"></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="smallLink" href="<?php echo URL2; ?>Treatment/exportPDF/"> PDF</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="smallLink" href="">Excel</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

so how could i call the function `getUsername()` from my **href**? is my script also wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<script>
    function getURL(){
        document.location = "<?php echo URL2; ?>Treatment/exportPDF/"+ $(".username").Text();
    }
</script>
<div  class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="Paragraph">Select a username</label>
            <p>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input name="username" type="text" class="longInput1"/>
                <span class="errorMessage"></span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="smallLink" href="javascript:getURL()"> PDF</a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="smallLink" href="">Excel</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i love your way , would you tell my how to corrent tht URL ?

Comment: @tottiroma, except the fact that it has errors and mix server side with client side code for no reason...

Answer (score 3):

> is my script also wrong?

**YES**

```
$(".username").Text();
```

Should be:

```
var value = $("input[name='username']").val();
window.location = "/treatment/exportPDF/" + value;
```

Change the HTML to:

```
<a class="smallLink" href="#" onclick="getUsername()"> PDF</a>
```

- `text`(not Text) (almost) equals to `innerHTML`
- `val` equals to `value`.
- `.` in css selectors is a class selector.

Comment: and how could i call it from HTML ?

Comment: would you tell me what should i write in HTML to call the function from my script ?

Comment: @tottiroma, you can write this: `<a class="smallLink" href="#" onclick="getUsername()"> PDF</a>` but you need to adjust the script with `window.location =...`

Comment: you the one man, i really thank you. it works very very very well :)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an `onmousedown` on your links, specify the link in the `href` attribute, and modify it `onclick`, like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo URL2; ?>Treatment/exportPDF/" onmousedown="this.href = this.href + $('[name=username]').val(); this.onmousedown = '';">
```

Comment: it gives me very very long url doesn't contain my text field value

Comment: Well, you might have copied 'php stuff' as I wrote it, corrected the answer to contain your original url. This should work properly. window.location is also a valid solution.

Comment: Is there a downside to use onmousedown instead of onclick? I'll be using this on a mobile/tablet friendly site.

Answer (score 1):

use this code in your script

```
       <script>
            function getUsername(){
                  alert(document.getElementById("username").value)
                return (document.getElementById("username").value)
            }
      </script>
```

and give id to textbox

```
          <input id=="username" name="username" type="text" class="longInput1"/>
```

Comment: You don't have to give an id to the input-field as we already have a name, see answers below.